# Electronic dance music (EDM)

Tags: halacha, music, employment, dance

I have two questions.

**1.** Is it permitted for a Jew to produce electronic dance music (no lyrics), which is usually played at clubs etc. where women and men will dance together (no gender separation but those "clubbers" are usually gentiles)?

**2.** Is it permitted for a Jew to perform (ie. play the music / be a dj) in such places?

Comment: Irving Berlin could ask a similar question.

Comment: I can't see a problem with #1. There are discussions about the type of music Jews SHOULD Listen to, and, similarly, the types of music Jews SHOULD produce, but from what I recall they are "suggestions" vs. halacha. (For many years, Shlomo Carlebach music could not be sung or played at weddings!) For #2 - how would being a DJ at a mixed dance affair be any different than being a regular guest? You are physically there!

Comment: @Clint Eastwood - so would De-Scribe http://myspace.com/describemusic

Comment: @DanF It differs because the DJ is there for parnassa

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman - good point... otherwise, you'd never be able to have live bands. Which, in some ways, is not a bad idea .... less noise, perhaps, and less cost ;-)

Comment: Who said a  band which could see women dancing is ok ,even for parnassah

Comment: @sam That wasn't an answer to the OP's question. It was an answer to @DanF's question, `[H]ow would being a DJ at a mixed dance affair be any different than being a regular guest?`

Comment: Hey Joe. It so happens I love EDM music. I'm thinking, vis-vis your question, that perhaps it might be important to consider the fact that EDM is heavy on sampling other people's music. I'm sure that Tiesto, Guetta, van Buuren, deadmau3, et. al. would be sued if they did not obtain permission from the copyright holders. Perhaps there is an even bigger halakhik issue listening to music that contained samples that were "stolen" (not credited, not paid for, not given permission, etc.)

Comment: By the way, David Guetta has a Jewish father. Rumor has it deadmau3 also has some Jewish near-relative as well. Just for your information if you didn't already know :)

Comment: @JJLL - You raise a good point regarding copyright issues. I'm not a tecchie (I still listen to the vinyl version of the White Album! Sometimes...) so I don't really understand how EDM is created and "mixed". But, at the event, the attendants have no clue what's legal or not. You may want to post your concern as a separate question. It's a good point!

Comment: DanF. Perhaps you know, vinyl is making a comeback, especially in the UK. Projekt (sp?), Rega, VPI, etc. are all still producing brand new turntables. Prices range from $300 or so to tens-of-thousands. So don't feel "bad" about listening to White Album in vinyl. Digital never did nor ever will sound as good as vinyl! Shabbat Shalom DanF.

Answer (score -1):

If the Jew has to put himself in the head-space of the dancers to produce the music then (1) should be assur because of kedoshim tiheyu, perushim min ha'arayos.

Comment: who said anything about producing music?